# How to load script component of a prefab on an AssetBundle in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, assetbundle

So I have a gameObject(Let's call it XX) and I have created a Prefab of XX that contains a script (the XX prefab has a script component). When I build the AssetBundle and I load XX on a button click the gameObject of XX loads correctly but the script component doesn't come along. Is there a way to load XX with the script component?
Thanks!

Comment: Taking a look at [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) it is platform-specific non-code Assets. This might help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/missing-scripts-on-loading-scene-asset-bundle.590824/

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to my question is that you create the asset bundle from your model-object and then through code you AddComponent to this. Something like this: `MyClass xx = anObject.AddComponent(typeof(MyClass)) as MyClass;`